# How to retrieve the likes for post in daily granularity in facebook api?

Tags: rest, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have tried by the calls:
post_id/reactions,post_id/likes
but I get zero data.
I have these permissions: ads_read,read_insights,ads_management,pages_manage_ads, pages_manage_posts, pages_read_user_content

Thanks in advance